# Aggregate and grouping in SQL

Tags: sql, mysql

Hi I am learning SQL (basic) and wanted to check on this question.

We define an employee's total earnings to be their monthly salary*months worked, and the maximum total earnings to be the maximum total earnings for any employee in the Employee table. Write a query to find the maximum total earnings for all employees as well as the total number of employees who have maximum total earnings. Then print these values as  space-separated integers.
The Employee table containing employee data for a company is described as follows:

[image]

Output Needed example: 69952 1
The maximum earnings value is 69952 . The only employee with earnings  is Kimberly, so we print the maximum earnings value (6995) and a count of the number of employees who have earned 69952  (which is 1) as two space-separated values.

I get the correct answer when I write this query:

```
Select salary*months, count(name)
from employee
where salary*months=(Select max(salary*months) from employee)
group by salary*months;
```

However I was wondering why won't this query work?

```
Select max(salary*months),count(name)
from employee
group by salary*months;
```

The query below is not grouping the maximum of salary*months but it does in the above query when salary*months is given the same value in a sub-query.
Any help on explaining this logic would be great.

Comment: Notice this _does_ work: `SELECT TOP 1 salary*months, COUNT(*) FROM employee GROUP BY salary*months ORDER BY salary*months DESC`

Comment: Apologies, that was MSSQL syntax. I meant: `SELECT salary*months, COUNT(*) FROM employee GROUP BY salary*months ORDER BY salary*months DESC LIMIT 1`

Comment: Thanks @RuudHelderman. The count is showing 1 which is not correct. It should show count of employees having maximum salary which is more than 1.

Comment: Works fine here. Please show me your test; I'll show you mine: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/90c05e/1

Answer (score 0):

In the first query, Group is not required,  if you apply the max or min function to the salary*months column. As you are applying the filter. So only max salary*months values will be retrieved.

> Select max(salary * months), count(name) from employee where (salary *
> months)=(Select max(salary * months) from employee)

In the second query apply order by and limit so that we can get max salary*months value.

> select salary*months, count(name) from employee group by 1 order by 1
> desc limit 1;

Comment: I understand the logic of second query you added but the count of name is incorrect. It shows 1 as count but the question asked total no. of employees with max salary which is not 1.